# QuickFix/n changing the datadictionary

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am trying to add some fields to the DataDictionary as per the documentation but cant find the DataDictionary.xml file. does nayone know where it can be found

Comment: It should normally be in the form `FIX<version>.xml`, e.g. `FIX42.XML` for FIX version 4.2. At least that's the case in QuickFIX/J, but it should be named similarly with any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It should reside in your project Folder under `packages\QuickFix.Net.1.8.0\spec\` (assuming you have installed QuickFix/N via Nuget). Or otherwise have a search for `FIX*.XML`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the original version of QuickFix/n from Connamara, then all data dictionary XML files are available in: [quickfixn/spec/fix/](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/tree/master/spec/fix) named `FIX<version>.xml`, as correctly written in earlier replies.

Also notice, that you need to explicitly specify dictionary file location when creating Acceptor or Initiator:
`SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(<XML file>);`

so in your project you may copy the XML file (for the version you are using) wherever you need, edit it and specify its location in the above code line.